# 7Zip add string to zip name

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I have a 7zip command line process that zips by date and its works well. The command creates a zip file with date IE `20121019.zip`.  However Id like to add a string to the file name. for example `20121019_PRIMARY.zip`.

Here is my current command

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a
 x:\Logs\HS\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.zip
 X:\Logs\HS\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%\* -xr!*.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use

`c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a x:\Logs\HS\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_PRIMARY.zip X:\Logs\HS\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%* -xr!*.zip`

instead, or have I missed something?